# Python rounding issue

Tags: python, rounding

I have come across a very strange issue in python. (Using python 2.4.x)

In windows:

```
>>> a = 2292.5
>>> print '%.0f' % a
2293
```

But in Solaris:

```
>>> a = 2292.5
>>> print '%.0f' % a
2292
```

But this is the same in both windows and solaris:

```
>>> a = 1.5
>>> print '%.0f' % a
2
```

Can someone explain this behavior? I'm guessing it's platform dependent on the way that python was compiled?

Comment: Note that if you want to consistently get the intuitive "round away from zero" behavior, you can use the C99/POSIX.1-2001 function "roundf".  I'm not sure if there are bindings for that in Python, or if it's available at all in Windows; if it's important to you, you could write a C module for it easily to include a third-party implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function ultimately in charge of performing that formatting is `PyOS_snprintf` 
(see [the sources](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/mysnprintf.c)).  As you surmise, that's unfortunately system-dependent, i.e., it relies on `vsprintf`, `vsnprintf` or other similar functions that are ultimately supplied by the platform's C runtime library (I don't recall if the C standard says anything about the '%f' formatting for floats that are "exactly midway" between two possible rounded values... but, whether the C standard is lax about this, or rather the C standard is strict but some C runtimes break it, ultimately is a pretty academic issue...).

Comment: I believe that some implementations (of C) round down when the previous digit is even and round up when it is odd

Comment: @gnibbler, that's a good accounting rule (even mandated by law in some jurisdictions, I think) -- but then accounting is invariably performed with decimal-based numbers, **not** binary floats, so in the context of floats this becomes somewhat moot;-).

Comment: I think the C standard mandates ISO 754, but that specifies several possible rounding modes (probably so as not to break existing FPU rounding hardware), two of which are "round to even" (glibc) and "round away from 0" (Windows CRT).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Rounding_modes.  "Round to even" is weird and pointless, but it's legal and we're stuck with it.

Comment: It's not weird and pointless. That rule means that on average all your roundings even out.

Comment: Only if the second-least significant digit of all your numbers are uniformly distributed between odd and even. I may be misunderstanding Benford's Law, but I'm pretty sure that's rarely the case.

Answer (score 2):

round() rounds toward the nearest even integer
"%n.nf" works the same way as round()
int() truncates towards zero

"rounding a positive number to the nearest integer
can be implemented by adding 0.5 and truncating"
-- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding

In Python you can do this with: `math.trunc( n + 0.5 )`
assuming n is positive of course...

Where "round half to even" is not appropriate, i now use
`math.trunc( n + 0.5 )` where i used to use `int(round(n))`

Comment: Actually, python doesn't round towards the nearest even integer: `if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done away from 0 (so. for example, round(0.5) is 1.0 and round(-0.5) is -1.0).` [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

Answer (score 0):

I is plataform dependent. You can find the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

It is good to user [ceil](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.ceil) or [floor](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.floor) when you know what you want (to round up or down).